# MongoDB get data at specific intervals in time

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have my data in MongoDb in the following format:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbaf"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:11.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 710.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 910.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 910.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854251.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb0"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:12.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 720.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 920.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 920.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854252.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb1"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:13.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 730.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 930.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 930.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854253.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb2"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:14.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 740.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 940.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 940.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854254.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb3"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:15.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 750.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 950.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 950.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854255.0
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb4"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:16.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 760.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 960.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 960.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854256.0
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb5"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:17.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 770.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 970.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 970.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854257.0
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb6"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:18.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 780.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 980.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 980.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854258.0
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb7"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:19.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 790.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 990.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 990.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854259.0
}

/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb8"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:20.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 800.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 0.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 0.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854260.0
}

/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb9"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:21.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 810.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 10.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 10.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854261.0
}

/* 12 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbba"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:22.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 820.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 20.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 20.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854262.0
}
```

What I would like to achieve is get the records at 5 sec intervals. So the output I expect should be

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbaf"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:11.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 710.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 910.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 910.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854251.0
}
/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb4"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:16.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 760.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 960.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 960.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854256.0
}
/* 11 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a40f49743bf8220c865cbb9"),
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2017-01-08T11:14:21.000Z"),
    "WIZ_VAR_10" : 810.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_11" : 10.0,
    "WIZ_VAR_12" : 10.0,
    "TIMESTAMP_EP" : 1483854261.0
}
```

So essentially I want to get the records at an interval. I checked the aggregation framework but could not find exact solution for the same.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$second](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/second/index.html) operator which takes seconds part from date `(0-60)` and then [$mod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) to take modulo `5` (`5` seconds interval). In your case you want to start with `11` so you should check if modulo is [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/index.html) to `1`. To use those operators directly in `$match` you need [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) which is available in MongoDB v 3.6:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [ { $mod: [ { $second: "$TIMESTAMP" }, 5 ] }, 1 ]
            }            
        }
    }
])
```

If you're using lower MongoDB version then you can try with [$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/index.html):

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $eq: [ { $mod: [ { $second: "$TIMESTAMP" }, 5 ] }, 1 ] },
                then: "$$KEEP",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }            
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Great thanks it worked. I just have one query that my data might start at odd or even intervals like in my case it was 14:11 it might also start at 14:10. How could I do it in the same query ?

Comment: I'd suggest two queries here to keep it simple: 1. get first date to determine even or odd 2. apply aggregation,

Comment: I was wondering how to extend the logic for minute/hour/day/week intervals meaning I would want to see my data at minute/hour/day/week boundaries. As $minute gives minutes from date time between 0-59 and I want to see say data at 5 min interval.

Comment: For instance for minutes you have to check if seconds part is equal to zero and perform $mod on minutes part and so on...